# Ansible can't run when vars are used in include_tasks

Tags: ansible

I have two playbooks *driver.yaml* invoking another play after converting from template called *main_driver.yml*

Main playbook *driver.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: Setup Services
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - var_input_driver.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Converting template to playbook
      template:
         src: template_for_driver.yaml.j2
         dest: main_driver.yaml
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: run roles
      include_tasks: main_driver.yaml
```

Content of *main_driver.yaml*

```yaml
---
- name: Setup Services
  vars:
    java_package: java-11-openjdk
    dock_version: 18.09.0

- name: Setup services
  include_role:
    name: configure-java
```

Receiving error as below:

> FAILED! => {"reason": "no module/action detected in task.\n\nThe error appears to be in 'main_driver.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Setup Services\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: I find the idea off including a task file just made out of a template rather odd and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

`vars` is not a module name but a task option. You should fix your included file like so:

```yaml
---
- name: Setup services
  include_role:
    name: configure-java
  vars:
    java_package: java-11-openjdk
    dock_version: 18.09.0
```

An other possible way would be:

```yaml
---
- name: Set variables
  set_fact:
    java_package: java-11-openjdk
    dock_version: 18.09.0

- name: Setup services
  include_role:
    name: configure-java
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working for be but is it possible to declare vars at the top level so that it applies to tasks and other roles? my objective here is to create the actual playbook dynamically with vars, tasks and roles using template and finally run it

Answer (score 0):

couple of things:

- main_driver.yaml seems to include itself (main_driver) - that probably won't work.
- the task file used with "include_tasks" should be a "pure" task file, not a playbook. In other words, it should not contain a playbook header (hosts, name, etc), but simply a list of tasks.

Im struggling to understand the logic in your example, maybe double-check that the file contents are correct?

Comment: Sorry for wrong file update, i have changed it now...